# Swift : Could not find an overload for '>' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: if-statement, swift, conditional-operator

I know this question is already asked with various other symbols replacing the '>' symbol in my case. But none of them is solving my issue. What I need to do is to check if the length of a search string is more than 2, and if it is, perform the search. For that I have written the following `if` condition:

```
if countElements(searchString) > 2 {}
```

Where searchString is a `String` object. But this line produces the error:

```
Could not find an overload for '>' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

I discovered that Swift doesn't convert values implicitly, so I tried the following code,

```
if Int(countElements(searchString)) > 2 {}
```

Still resulting in the same issue. What is wrong here?

**EDIT**

The searchString comes from this delegate:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {

    if countElements(searchString) > 2
    {

    }
    return false
 }
```

Comment: Did you try this: `if countElements(searchString) > Int(2) {}`?

Comment: Same issue. Already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The actual problem was how swift takes variables. Adding an exclamation mark after the `searchString` solved the issue. Corrected code:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {

    if countElements(searchString!) > 2
    {

    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Well, actually not that strange. It is how Swift works. We use the ! in swift to say that the value is not null and it surely has some value.

Comment: Not when it's an implicitly unwrapped optional. Why should we force unwrap something that is already unwrapped implicitly?

Comment: Hmm.. Now that is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the code you have included in your question. If you try the following in a playground it works just fine:

```
var searchString = "foo"

if countElements(searchString) > 2 {
  println("It's a long string!")
}
```

Can you provide a really simple example that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Please see my edit. The searchString is from a delegate